# Touchpad settings not available on ubuntu 16.04 for dell latitude

Tags: touchpad, dell

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 on my new latitude E5570.  The mouse/touchpad settings only has the General and Mouse sections, nothing to change the touchpad options (like inverse scroll).  The xinput command returns:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So it appears that it isn't recognizing the touchpad.  How do I get ubuntu to load the correct driver?

Comment: I have the same issue with a Dell E5270.